# HTTP 403 ERROR while uploading python package to PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

I am following [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial to create a simple python package and upload it to Pypi. For some reason, when I run the command `py -m twine upload --repository pypi dist/*`, I get the following error:

```
HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.
```

I think it is because of my API Token, I have it from Pypi, but I do not know where to put it. I am enterring all of the commands correctly and I am in the proper file folders.

Can someone please help? I have my API token, I just don't know where to put it.

Comment: pls post setup.py or check that you have auther and auther email there.

Comment: HTTPError: 403 Forbidden : It is related to authentication and access permission. It is a client side issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when executing the `twine upload dist*` command.

The following solved it for me:

Create a `.pypirc` file in your home directory `${HOME}/.pypirc`, and add the following content:

```
[distutils]
  index-servers =
    pypi
    YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

[pypi]
  username = __token__
  password = YOUR_API_TOKEN

[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]
  repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
  username = __token__
  password = YOUR_API_TOKEN
```

Be sure to fill in your data in this file:

1. `YOUR_API_TOKEN` from https://pypi.org/manage/account/token/ (can only be found once, so be sure to store it somewhere save).
2. `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` which is the name of your project according to pypi.